# Weblogic thin client usage license in other servers

Tags: java, jms, weblogic, weblogic12c

I am trying to connect to weblogic JMS using weblogic thin client (wlthint3client.jar) from tomcat.

My question is regarding licensing part . Is the wlthint3client.jar open source, Can we use it in production if we don't have weblogic server license.

Documentation mentioned like it can be used by other severs but I couldn't find the licensing part.